# Discord bot not responding for commands

Tags: python, discord, bots

I try to make a discord bot on python but he not responding for any command.
How i can fix it?

````
import requests
import random
from discord.ext import commands



intents = discord.Intents.all()


Away = commands.Bot(command_prefix="$", intents=intents)

@Away.event
async def on_message(ctx):
    print(ctx.content)

@Away.command
async def say(ctx):
    await ctx.send(ctx.content)

Away.run("token")```
````

Answer (score 0):

Have you made sure you have enabled message content intents in the discord developer portal? See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74490633/discord-py-getting-empty-messages/74631246#74631246) for instructions.