# Discord.py getting empty messages

Tags: python, discord.py

I was developing a small discord bot for some time, and it was working fine until I started testing to play mp3 in a voice channel.

I was following this question because **discord.py** throwed an error that I needed pynacl lib: [RuntimeError: PyNaCl library needed in order to use voice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63859231/runtimeerror-pynacl-library-needed-in-order-to-use-voice)

Bot stopped working after running this command: `pip install -U discord.py[voice]`

Now I don't get any message content:

[image]

I did try to `pip uninstall discord.py[voice]` and reinstall base with `pip install discord.py`

How can I get the message contents now?

Comment: You need [message_content](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=message_content#discord.Intents.message_content) intents

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71558677/14327609) should fix your issue.

Comment: I had the intents but I just had to give administrator to the bot as it was an admin channel

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that the message_content intent is configured correctly on both the [discord developer portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications) and in the code:

```
intents = discord.Intents()
intents.message_content = True
client = discord.Bot(intents=intents)
```